# Simple group with central extension by Prüfer group and an automorphism of infinite order

Tags: gr.group-theory

Do you know of any perfect group $G$ such that

**1)** $Z(G)$ is a Prüfer $p$-group for some prime $p$

**2)** $G/Z(G)$ is infinite simple (or a direct product of infinitely many finite simple groups)

**3)** there is an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ acting on $Z(G)$ as an automorphism of infinite order.

I can construct a group with the first two properties, but I cannot impose the third property.

Comment: I mean when G/Z(G) is a direct product of infinitely many simple group, but I will be happy also without that restriction, so I'll probably delete it.

Comment: The (now erased) assumption to act trivially on $G/Z(G)$ is hopeless: indeed assume it; write $\alpha(g)=gz(g)$, with $z$ a function $G\to Z(G)$. Then $z$ is a homomorphism. Since $G$ is perfect, $z$ is trivial and hence $\alpha$ is the identity.

Comment: You guess right!